# Extract a specific table and image from .docx file using python

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am trying to extract a specific table from word document which falls right after the heading "List Of Abbreviations " and an image that is right after a heading "Graphical Study" in a .docx file . I have been able to extract the headers using python-docx code but how do I parse the document using the headers or their position to retrieve the image and the table.In beautiful soup I am using `if re.match("Graphical", img.previous_sibling.text)` to search for my image . My python docx code is :

```
from docx import *

document = Document('data/p21.docx')
document.save('test-new.docx')

for content in document.paragraphs:
    if content.style.name=='Heading 1' or content.style.name=='Heading 2' or content.style.name=='Heading 3':
        print (content.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
...
table = document.tables[table_number]
...
```

Where table_number is the number of the table in the document starting from 0. (1st table is index number 0, 2nd is index number 1 and so on...)

Comment: Yes, that is a workaround I have been using but the table is at different positions in different documents so I need to find a generalized code for all documents. Any way I can detect the table number which falls right after the heading?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the structured information from docx file using the xml. Try this:

```
doc = Document("file.docx")
headings = [] #extract only headings from your code
tables = [] #extract tables from your code
tags = []
all_text = []
schema = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
for elem in doc.element.getiterator():
    if elem.tag == schema + 'body':
        for i, child in enumerate(elem.getchildren()):
            if child.tag != schema + 'tbl':
                 node_text = child.text
                 if node_text:
                     if node_text in headings:
                         tags.append('heading')
                     else:
                         tags.append('text')
                     all_text.append(node_text)
             else:
                 tags.append('table')
        break
```

After the above code you will have the list of tags that will show the structure of document heading, text and table then you can map the respective data from the lists.

Also, check the data from the tag list to get the heading of a table. You can iterate and get the table where your heading is present